# I get this error that I don't understand why, using NoRM and Mongo in my MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb, norm

Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient'.

I don't understand why it happen and how to deal with it. I use Ninject, my application is based on mvcstarter.codeplex.com/ what I do is delete some user or pages from my database and it happen for no reason(that I can find).

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

*Edited 
Also, after a while it get back to normal and I can fetch my data from Mongo... My unit tests work fine...

Here's my code for my session :

```
public class MongoSession : ISession{

    private readonly Mongo _server;

    public MongoSession()
    {
        //this looks for a connection string in your Web.config - you can override this if you want
        _server = Mongo.Create("MongoDB");
    }

    public T Single<T>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression) where T : class {
        return _server.GetCollection<T>().AsQueryable().Where(expression).SingleOrDefault();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> All<T>() where T : class {
        return _server.GetCollection<T>().AsQueryable();
    }

    /*public void Add<T>(T item) where T : class {
        _provider.DB.GetCollection<T>().Insert(item);
    }*/

    public void Save<T>(IEnumerable<T> items) where T : class {
        foreach (T item in items) {
            Save(item);
        }
    }

    public void Save<T>(T item) where T : class {
        var errors = DataAnnotationsValidationRunner.GetErrors(item);
        if (errors.Count() > 0)
        {
            throw new RulesException(errors);
        }
        _server.Database.GetCollection<T>().Save(item);
    }

    //this is just some sugar if you need it.
    /*public T MapReduce<T>(string map, string reduce) {
        T result = default(T);
        using (MapReduce mr = _provider.Server.CreateMapReduce()) {
            MapReduceResponse response =
                mr.Execute(new MapReduceOptions(typeof(T).Name) {
                                                                    Map = map,
                                                                    Reduce = reduce
                                                                });
            MongoCollection<MapReduceResult<T>> coll = response.GetCollection<MapReduceResult<T>>();
            MapReduceResult<T> r = coll.Find().FirstOrDefault();
            result = r.Value;
        }
        return result;
    }*/

    public void Delete<T>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression) where T : class
    {
        var items = All<T>().Where(expression);
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            Delete(item);
        }
    }

    public void Delete<T>(T item) where T : class
    {
        _server.GetCollection<T>().Delete(item);
    }

    public void Drop<T>() where T : class
    {
        _server.Database.DropCollection(typeof(T).Name);

    }

    /*public void CommitChanges()
    {
        //mongo isn't transactional in this way... it's all firehosed
    }*/

    public void Dispose() {
        _server.Dispose();
    }


}
```

And the calling code would be something like this, my _session is pass to my Controller in the contrutor using Ninject, with the binding in my global.cs   :

```
Bind<ISession>().To<MongoSession>().InSingletonScope();



public virtual ActionResult Liens()
    {
        var shortcutLionks = _session.All<ShortcutLinks>().ToList();
        ViewData.Model = shortcutLionks.Count > 0 ? shortcutLionks[0] : new ShortcutLinks();
        return View();
    }
```

EDITED :

Here's the detail of my error :

> Stack Trace : at
>   System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.GetStream()
>   at Norm.Connection.GetStream() at
>   Norm.Connection.Write(Byte[] bytes,
>   Int32 start, Int32 size) at
>   Norm.Protocol.Messages.QueryMessage`2.Execute()
>   at
>   Norm.MongoQueryExecutor`3.d__0.MoveNext()
>   at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1
>   source) at
>   Norm.Linq.MongoQueryExecutor.Execute[T]()
>   at
>   Norm.Linq.MongoQueryProvider.ExecuteQuery[T](Expression
>   expression) at
>   Norm.Linq.MongoQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression
>   expression) at
>   System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1
>   source) at
>   Domain.Storage.MongoDB.MongoSession.Single[T](Expression`1
>   expression) in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DubeLoiselle\Domain\Storage\MongoDB\MongoSession.cs:line
>   21 at
>   Domain.Storage.MongoDB.MongoRepositoryBase`1.Single(Expression`1
>   expression) in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DubeLoiselle\Domain\Storage\MongoDB\MongoRepositoryBase.cs:line
>   26 at
>   SPK.CMS.Domain.Repository.PageRepository.GetHomePage()
>   in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DubeLoiselle\SPK.CMS.Domain\Repository\PageRepository.cs:line
>   146 at
>   Web.Controllers.PageController.Home()
>   in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DubeLoiselle\Web\Controllers\PageController.cs:line
>   26 at
>   Web.Controllers.PageController.RedirectTo(String
>   url1, String url2, String url3) in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DubeLoiselle\Web\Controllers\PageController.cs:line
>   50 at lambda_method(ExecutionScope ,
>   ControllerBase , Object[] ) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor
>   actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClassd.b__a()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext
>   preContext, Func`1 continuation) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters,
>   ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor,
>   IDictionary`2 parameters) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName)

**Edited again :**

Before I get this error I trap this one :

Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Stack Trace : at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) at Norm.Connection.Write(Byte[] bytes, Int32 start, Int32 size) at Norm.Protocol.Messages.QueryMessage`2.Execute() at Norm.MongoQueryExecutor`3.d__0.MoveNext() at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at Norm.Linq.MongoQueryExecutor.Execute[T]() at Norm.Linq.MongoQueryProvider.ExecuteQuery[T](Expression expression) at Norm.Linq.MongoQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression) at System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source) at Domain.Storage.MongoDB.MongoSession.Single[T](Expression`1 expression) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DubeLoiselle\Domain\Storage\MongoDB\MongoSession.cs:line 21 at Domain.Storage.MongoDB.MongoRepositoryBase`1.Single(Expression`1 expression) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DubeLoiselle\Domain\Storage\MongoDB\MongoRepositoryBase.cs:line 26 at SPK.CMS.Domain.Repository.PageRepository.GetHomePage() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DubeLoiselle\SPK.CMS.Domain\Repository\PageRepository.cs:line 146 at SPK.CMS.Domain.Repository.PageRepository.GetByUrl(String url1, String url2, String url3) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DubeLoiselle\SPK.CMS.Domain\Repository\PageRepository.cs:line 195 at Web.Controllers.PageController.RedirectTo(String url1, String url2, String url3) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DubeLoiselle\Web\Controllers\PageController.cs:line 52 at lambda_method(ExecutionScope , ControllerBase , Object[] ) at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClassd.b__a() at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)

Comment: Anyone has an idea?! after a recycle of the IIS app pool it gets back to normal.

Comment: I can reproduce my error when I do lots of refresh in my web page very fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem, I close my Session object in my controller in the OnActionExecuted()

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        _session.Dispose();
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
```

Hope it can helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the underlying TcpClient have been disconnected from the server.

You should open an `IMongo` connection at the last moment, only to query the NoSQL datastore and dispose it. There is a connection pool that keeps connections opened and remove dead connections to lower the cost of using `Mongo.Create`.

Keeping connection opened for too long will cause you problems when you'll have many clients simultaneously.

Comment: I'm using Ninject, I think it should handle the connections for me? I based my project on [mvc starter site from Rob](http://mvcstarter.codeplex.com/)