# Mongo DB service stopping automatically

Tags: mongodb

I have setup mongodb as a service in my windows server 2008 r2 server. Last night  my windows server crashed and since then my mongodb service is not running as expected. It stops unexpectedly anytime and is behaving erratically.

I am not sure what could be the reason. let me know what can be done so that database mongodb behaves responsibly.

Thanks

Comment: have you checked the log files?

Comment: ok, so with deeper inspection with Mongo Log files, the problem seems not with Mongo but with a .NET implmentation of it. I am using Norm library with MongoDb and its giving Connection Timeout error. Any help with this.. why so.. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could post more infomation about your error that would be helpful, but this sounds a lot like this question ...

[Norm.MongoException: Connection timeout trying to get connection from connection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3450501/296167)

**The basic problem seemed to be connections that weren't being closed?**

Comment: yup my bad. I was not disposing off a connection in one of my repositories.

Comment: 11 years later, I have the same problem :)